# Notepad++ Regular Express with angle bracket data

Tags: regex, notepad++

Id' like to replace text with angle bracket as follows:

`<p> <b id="docs-guid-785896d2-1" >Choose </span> <span style="font-size: 15px; ">barren</span> <span > passage.</span></b> </p>\r\n', <b id="docs-guid-785896d2-6" > <span >empty</span></b> </p>\r\n\r\n<div>&nbsp;</div>\r\n', '<p> <b id="docs-guid-785896d2-665" > <span >wheat</span></b> </p>\r\n'`

all data is one line.
and i tried to remove b-tag like `"<b id="docs-guid-785896d2-1" > xxxx </b>"` => `xxxx`

i used `"<b id="docs-guid-(.*)" >(.*)</b>"` & `"\2"` to remove that tag, but only one string founded (of all 3)...

could you somebody help me to find & replace all 3 pairs..
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the lazy version of `(.*)` by adding a question mark:

```
<b id="docs-guid-(.*?)" >(.*?)</b>
                    ^       ^
```

Otherwise you'll match too much and the replace will remove more than necessary.

Or better yet, use negated class for some more efficiency:

```
<b id="docs-guid-[^"]+" >(.*?)</b>
```

Here, replace by `$1`